# Communication between two android devices

Tags: android

Is it possible for two android devices to communicate without using carrier services

Comment: Can you be more specific? Of course, you can use Bluetooth connection if it is supported by both devices, or even WiFi: latest Android versions allow an Android device to generate a WiFi access point. There are also implementations of the WiFi Direct protocol. If you mean a direct access through 3G radio access, short answer: no.

Comment: NFC is another way to communicate assuming that you have two NFC-supporting devices. Vincent is right, you need to be more specific.

Comment: Oh yes, NFC, which gives other ideas: using software to generate QR Code and then uses a QR Code reader with the phone camera :-) Plenty of solutions :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can communicate over http. Lars Vogel has a great tutorial on it: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html

Also you can think about using REST in combination with this.

Comment: thanks guys... I'll look in to these solutions. I was just thinking of making an app for a presentation on communication between android devices

Comment: Good that you like it. If it will help you, I can also post some code on making an http request and getting response as REST and then interpreting it. It has taken me some time to figure it out.